# Why is this jump() method for a sprite not working?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, sprite

My game only has 2 classes right now, "MyGdxGame" and "Player". I've added a method `jump()` to my Player class and overridden the `touchDown()` method to call jump every time the screen is tapped:

```
public void jump() {

    startTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
    elapsedTime = TimeUtils.timeSinceNanos(startTime);

    boolean jumpTime = elapsedTime < 2000000001;

    while (jumpTime) {
    moveBy(xSpeed, ySpeed);
    }
    moveBy(xSpeed, -ySpeed);
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    //moveBy(xSpeed, ySpeed);
    jump();
    return true;
}
```

Right now when the screen is tapped the sprite goes up but doesn't come back down. before the screen is tapped the sprite is moving from left to right at constant speed xSpeed. Any ideas?

**edit: I built my project then ran it again. It freezes when I tap the screen then crashes lol**

Answer (score 1):

The boolean `jumpTime` is never getting updated inside the while loop in the **jump()** method.

Try:

```
startTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
long jumpTime= 2000000001;

while (TimeUtils.timeSinceNanos(startTime) < jumpTime) {
   moveBy(xSpeed, ySpeed);
}

moveBy(xSpeed, -ySpeed);
```

Comment: Oh I see.. I made the changes and even though it stops the app from crashing, the sprite doesn't jump :( the game pauses for 2 seconds when the screen is tapped then returns to normal